# spring boot hot reload when jar file changed

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar

Spring boot project, build and package a jar file then upload it to the server, run it:

`java -jar xxx.jar`

How can I make it auto reload when I upload a new jar file?

Comment: You want to hot reload inside IDE??

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips no, I want it reload on server when the jar file changed.

Comment: How do you change the jar file?? Just replace with new jar?? In that case, you have to stop and start jar anyway..

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips I use jenkins to package a jar file and copy it to replace the old one.

Comment: In that case you have to stop and start.. No other way

Comment: @AnandVarkeyPhilips thanks, any other suggestion?

Comment: sorry.. I don't think so.. You may ask the same in : https://gitter.im/spring-projects/spring-boot

Answer (score 0):

add Spring Boot DevTools to your dependencies for developer friendly options like auto restart of the server:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: This only help when local develop